# Return Integer with Prolog

Tags: prolog, successor-arithmetics

I try to understand prolog right now. I want to give the input: `convert(s(s(s(X))),Y)` and the output should be `Y = 3`.

```
convert(s(0), 1).
convert(s(s(0)), 2).
convert(s(X),Y) :- convert(X,Y is (Y+1)).
```

Those are my rules right now, but only the inputs:
`convert(s(0), 1)`. And
`convert(s(s(0)), 2)`. work.

If my recursion would work right, I wouldn't need the rule: `convert(s(s(0)), 2)`.
Can someone help me with that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here:

- `Y is Y+1`, does not makes any sense in Prolog; and
- note that you here actually have written a *functor*.

Prolog sees this as a call:

```
convert(X,is(Y,Y+1))
```

where `is(Y,Y+1)` is **not** called, but passed as a functor. In Prolog there is no clear input and output. You call predicates and through unification, you obtain results.

We can however solve the problem by using recursion: the `convert/2` of `0` is of course `0`:

```
convert(0,0).
```

and the convert of an `s(X)`, is the convert of `X` plus one:

```
convert(s(X),R) :-
    convert(X,Y),
    R is Y+1.
```

Or putting these together:

```
convert(0,0).
convert(s(X),R) :-
    convert(X,Y),
    R is Y+1.
```

Now we can call the predicate to list all Peano numbers and the corresponding number, as well as converting a Peano number into a number. We can also validate if a Peano number is a normal number.

Unfortunately we can not use this predicate to obtain the Peano number from a given number: it will unify with the Peano number, but in a attempt to look for another Peano number, will get stuck into an infinite loop.

We can use the `clpfd` library to help us with this:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

convert(0,0).
convert(s(X),R) :-
    R #> 0,
    Y #= R-1,
    convert(X,Y).
```

Comment: thanks, it works! But why is it important to give a big letter like R:
convert(s(X),R)

But why is not convert(s(X),r) working?

Comment: @Runner: because variables start with uppercases, constants are lowercase. This is not a convention (so failing to do so will make the program incorrect). Without wanting to sound annoying or anything like that, perhaps you should look up some fundamentals about Prolog.

Comment: While correct, your clpfd-version is extremely inefficient, as it requires many temporary variables. What about an efficient version? Ah, and s(X), indeed.